# Preventing files inside a folder to be backed up icloud

Tags: ios, icloud

Thanks in advance for help. 
I have excluded a folder from being backed up by iCloud but still it is backing up the files and when i visit iCould it is backed up. i use the following code to exclude the directory from being back up.

```
- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
// assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]);


NSError *error = nil;
BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
if(!success){
NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);
}
return success;
}
```

and i call the above method as bellow

```
NSArray *Paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *libraryDir = [Paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *downloadFolder = [libraryDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"downloads"];
NSError *error;
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:downloadFolder])
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:downloadFolder withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]; //Create folder

NSURL *documentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:downloadFolder];
[self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:documentURL];
```

Answer (score 0):

import this sys/xattr.h

```
- (BOOL) addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtPath: (NSString *) path { 
    BOOL success = NO; 

    const char* filePath = [path fileSystemRepresentation]; 
    const char* attrName = "com.apple.MobileBackup"; 

    void* check = (void *)&NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey; 
    if (check != NULL) { 
        // First try and remove the extended attribute if it is present 
        int result = getxattr(filePath, attrName, NULL, sizeof(u_int8_t), 0, 0); 
        if (result != -1) { 
            // The attribute exists, we need to remove it 
            int removeResult = removexattr(filePath, attrName, 0); 
            if (removeResult == 0) { 
                NSLog(@"Removed extended attribute on item at path %@", path); 
            } 
        } 
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path]; 
        success = [url setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES] forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: nil]; 
    } else { 
        // iOS 5.0.1 and lower 
        u_int8_t attrValue = 1; 
        int result = setxattr(filePath, attrName, &attrValue, sizeof(attrValue), 0, 0); 
        success = (result == 0); 
    } 
    NSLog(@"Add skip backup attribute for item at path: %@, result: %d", path, success); 
    return success; 
}
```

i hope this will work...